# AFK command discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have already made an AFK command that changes the user's nickname. Here is my code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content.includes('start-afk')) {
  message.member
   .setNickname(`${message.author.username} [AFK]`)
   .catch((error) => message.channel.send("Couldn't update your nickname."));
 }
 if (message.content.includes('end-afk')) {
  message.member
   .setNickname('')
   .catch((error) => message.channel.send("Couldn't update your nickname."));
 }
});
```

I want it to add an AFK reason to be shown whenever the AFK User is pinged and if the AFK user talks then his AFK is removed. I tried however I was unsure how to do it.

Comment: Can you supply us with your attempt and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the bot to remember who is AFK and maybe the reason for it, you'll have to use a database to store these pieces of information.

You could use `npm i quick.db`, which is a really simple database to use.

Here's an example code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    // checks if the message author is afk
    if (db.has(message.author.id + '.afk')) {
        message.reply("Oh you're back ! i removed your afk")
        db.delete(message.author.id + '.afk')
        db.delete(message.author.id + '.messageafk')
    }
    if (message.content.includes('start-afk')) {
        message.member.setNickname(`${message.author.username} [AFK]`).catch(error => message.channel.send("Couldn't update your nickname."));
        // then here you use the database :
        db.set(message.author.id + '.afk', 'true')
        db.set(message.author.id + '.messageafk', message.content.split(' ').slice(2))

        // I made .slice(2) so that in the message array it also delete the command and the "start-afk"
    }
    if (message.content.includes('end-afk')) {
        message.member.setNickname('').catch(error => message.channel.send("Couldn't update your nickname."));
        // Here you delete it
        db.delete(message.author.id + '.afk')
        db.delete(message.author.id + '.messageafk')
    }
});
```

Then, whenever the user gets pinged:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    // If one of the mentions is the user
    message.mentions.users.forEach(user => {
        if (db.has(user.id + '.afk')) message.reply('the user ' + user.tag + ' is afk !')
    })
})
```

Comment: is there any way you can make it only for a particular guild?

Answer (score -1):

1. Well first you would need a place to store the reason.
2. Then you get the reason from the end of the message.
3. Then store the reason with the user id of the user.
4. Then inside of the message listener, check if the author of the message is inside the array/map or whatever u choose to store the data in.
5. If the user doesnt exist inside the afk "list" just ignore
6. If the user exist inside the afk "list" just remove them from the afk "list".
7. Then just check if there is a mention inside the message by doing message.mentions.users.first() if a mentions exists just get the users afk reason from the list and send it to the channel.
8. Then if the user does end afk just remove them from the "list".

That's the idea anyways